# Filter out periodic data

Tags: machine-learning

I have N (movement detection) sensors. (N is determined. Usually five.)

All sensors are connected to one wireless AP (access point/network router).

Each sensor sends two types of data to the wireless AP.

One is heartbeat data with a constant frequency, and the other is sensed data (if a movement is detected).

Each sensor has a different frequency and I know the frequencies.

The AP encrypts each data and outputs a fixed size 512 bytes of data.

As soon as it encrypts one data, the AP sends it to a next router.

(The source address represents the AP not the sensor's address)

I observe the packets (encrypted data) in the next router.

(the data have some noises, because there are some delays in the AP)

***What I want to do is to differentiate heartbeat packets from the mixed packets.***

As the heartbeat packets are a mixture of N periodic packets, so I think it is possible.

***Is there any tool or scheme for it??***

For example, an observed data (of two sensors with frequency 3 and 2) is {1, 2, 3.9, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 16.1, ...}.

Then the output might be {sensor1: (1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, ...), sensor2: (2, 3.9, 4, 6, 8, 9.9, 12, 14, 16.1), sensed data (not heartbeat): (11)}.

(Or maybe probabilities.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need some clarification here^^: Question A: One Byte one data point? and B: Byte order = time order?

Comment: @ElBurro Thanks for your reply. One data points 512 bytes (or, one packet).

Comment: Still a bit confused so the 512 bytes would be this, right?  {1, 2, 3.9, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 16.1, ...}

Comment: @ElBurro Oh, {1, 2, 3.9... } means 'time'. In time 1, a packet (512 bytes) is observed. Likewise, in time 2, one packet (512 bytes) is observed. And so on. Thanks. (The number of bytes are not important. Just I wanted to let you know that the size does not imply anything.)

Comment: Do you also now the starting time or has this to be estimated. Example do yu know it starts at 1 or could it also start at 1.5 with everything shifted by 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

If both frequency and shift (delta_t) are known you can use something like an abs( (sin(phi*t + delta_t)) to be used as probability density function PDF for background (periodically recurrent data). If you then have a data point with a low background probability you can select it. This has the caveat that it does not work if data is recorded at the same time but then I guess you have to check the content anyway. The sinus function might not be the optimal implementation but is more too help you visualize it. I would just use gaussians with an appropriate width and stack them for the points when you expect data. So your global PDF could be a stack of many small gaussians. If you do not know the initial shift you probably you have to fit it on data.